# how to get most like, most commented and most viewed topic from database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database table having number of likes, number of comments and number of views and i need to get the Most Likes, Most comments and Most views row Please help me out i am attaching the database picture you will get the more clear idea what i need to do, thanks in advance

Table:

[image: database table image]

Comment: What do you want the results to look like?

Comment: `ORDER BY` ????

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend taking the [tour] and checking out the [help] to start off. Note that @TomFuller helped you out and embedded the image rather than a click-through, do that in the future. On your question, what have you tried? What were the results, and how did they differ from what you were expecting?

Comment: i just wanted to get Most Liked, Most commented and Most viewed rows nothing else.

Comment: Are you trying to get 3 separate rows or the row that has the most total likes + comments + views?

Comment: need to figure out how to make yoru question more generic, and then google that generic question.

Comment: What if two or more rows are tied?

Comment: @RAY Yes i want to get the row that has the most total likes + comments + views

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE title =
   ( SELECT title
       FROM table
     ORDER BY likes+comments+views DESC
     LIMIT 1
    ) ;
```

Comment: No.  The second query does not work as written.  Nor can it easily be fixed.

Comment: your query is showing the max values of each factor means, showing max value of likes, max value of comments and same for views, but i don't need this. my question is i need the row that has max likes and max comments and max views at a time. in this sense you can take this example i need that article or post that has most likes, most comments and most views.

Comment: Can you be more specific... Whats your intent on maximum...? Is it summing up all three should give you a max value?

Comment: @Teja - (Re: earlier comment) "just removing the group by" will lead to a random `Title`, probably the first in the table.  My point is... There are nasties in using `GROUP BY`, and you are being bitten by them; I don't want you to recommend them to others.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the row with the most total likes, comments, and views:

```
SELECT id, title, (likes + comments + views) AS total
FROM table
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Note:  this is slightly more efficient since it does not use a subquery.